# Pool for std::shared_ptr memory

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, memory-pool

My goal is to have std::shared_ptr allocate ALL of its memory using a pool rather than the global memory resource (i.e., heap).

From what I can tell, might possible using constructor (6) from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

The Alloc template argument would need to be a reference/pointer type to my pool.  However, I also know that this pool needs to allocate not just my type but some internal wrapper that std::shared_ptr uses for reference counting.  std::make_shared allocates this magic structure and my type in the same block of memory.  Thus, my pool would need to do the same thing.

However, my memory pool has the following type:

```
template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
class pool {
    //...
    template <typename ... ARGS>
    T* create(ARGS&& ... args);
    //...
};
```

To be used in std::shared_ptr, I think I would somehow need to get a hold of the internal type used by std::shared_ptr.

The same thing would apply with the deleter.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you want everything allocated in this way, the managed object as well as the control block, then you should use [`std::allocate_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared), not one of the `std::shared_ptr` constructors directly. The `Alloc` type should not be a reference or pointer. It should be a class type satisfying the [_Allocator requirements_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator). An allocator type is typically templated on all possible value types it could allocate for and `allocate_shared` can access that through the `rebind` membe

Comment: When you look at the constructors of ```std::allocator``` here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocator , you see the "rebinding" pattern in the last line of constructors. Basically, ```std::allocate_shared``` will use the converting constructor for the allocator to get one specific for this internal type. That's how you get the type and your pool has to handle this type change at runtime.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801417/using-stdallocate-shared-with-polymorphic-resource-allocators) help? (maybe with the change to use `std::pmr::unsynchronized_pool_resource`)